# How to change root's shell back to bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, root, chsh

I tried to change root's shell with `chsh` command, but now I get an error when I try to connect as root with `sudo -i`.

```
$ sudo -i
sudo: /usr/bin/bash: command not found
```

What do I have to modify to get the `bash` shell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that you have not modified the path or created symlink, the default path to the `bash` binary is `/bin/bash`, not `/usr/bin/bash`.

The error is occurring because you have set the `root`'s shell as `/usr/bin/bash` in `/etc/passwd` like:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/bin/bash
```

You need to change that to `/bin/bash`:

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash root
```

or do:

```
sudo vipw
```

and make the modifications manually.

You can obviously choose any other shell of your choice, just make sure that the path is correct. A common place to look for shell paths is `/etc/shells` file which contains the full paths to all the valid login shells on the system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the same time, I noticed I could modify the path with `sudo emacs /etc/passwd`

Comment: @SandraRoss If you are confident you can obviously do that. But i would  suggest `vipw` as it will do the sanity checkings (e.g. syntax) over the changes to make sure everything is in place.

Comment: If you don't want to usse vipw, you can check the integrity of /etc/passwd with pwck