# Can not root: after removing ZSH and returning to default bash

Tags: bash, root, zsh, su

I can not `$ sudo su` everytime, I enter the command, the terminal says :

> can not execute /usr/bin/zsh no such file or directory

How to return to default bash of Ubuntu and make bash as default bash?

Comment: How did you install Zsh, and how did you remove it? What changes did you make to your setup while it was installed? What is the output of `getent passwd root`? Please [edit] to add.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change to bash shell? - Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855211/how-to-change-to-bash-shell-error)

Answer (score -2):

First remove the symlink and make a new symlink that makes the default to previous bash

```
sudo ln -sv /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Exit the terminal, and start a new terminal.

Now, change root's shell. Edit the passwd file - Start any editor and search for `zsh`.

I used vim - `$ sudo vim /etc/passwd`

Searched `/zsh`. For me it was on the first line:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/bin/zsh
```

changed

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

<kbd>Esc</kbd>, `:wq`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> - This is for saving and exiting Vim.

For other editors like gedit and nano, just search for `zsh`, edit line, then save and exit.

Then exit Bash and restart your PC.

Comment: Don't re-link /bin/sh! It shouldn't break anything, but [/bin/sh is meant to be Dash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh). Everything else in this answer is fine tho.

Comment: edit `/etc/passwd`, change `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/bin/zsh` to `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash` works for me.